# Creating an SQL table that auto arranges according to date

Tags: mysql

I have really thought about this but I can't figure out a way around it. Am trying to create a table that auto arranges to make sure date is in increasing order, irrespective of the sequence used to insert them.
This is an account book that generates balance automatically, so I don't want to mess up the occurrence of events.
Thanks for your help.

```
$sql2 = "CREATE TABLE `suppliers`.`$name1` (`SN` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL , INDEX `SN` (`SN`), `RecordDate` DATE NOT NULL, `Quantity` VARCHAR(10) NULL, `Description` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, `Rate` VARCHAR(10) NULL, `Amount` VARCHAR(10) NULL, `Payment` VARCHAR(10) NULL, `Balance` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, `Receipt` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT'', `RecordedBy` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, `UpdatedBy` VARCHAR(30) NULL, `UpdatedDate` DATETIME NULL) ENGINE = MyISAM";      
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
```

[image: sample of mysql table]
I want number 3 to automatically displace number 2, even if number 2 was recorded first and calculate balance according to occurrance of events

Comment: Why not just apply an order when querying the data? If you can't do that, please specify the engine used with as much detail as possible (MySQL, MS SQL, Oracle, etc.)

Comment: The engine is MyISAM. Let's say the table already has three rows and I want to record a fourth event which occurred before the three already recorded. I want that fourth event to take the first row and others follow after it

Comment: just insert (or update) with `now()` ?

Comment: wrong solution Drew...I have updated the question so you can understand it more, am not trying to generate current date and time. Thanks for the comment though

Comment: I don't really get what you actually want. 3 should replace 2? why? what is the underlying logic for that? please specify.

Comment: Notionally, the rows in a relational table have no inherent order; any order is imposed at query time by use of the `ORDER BY` clause. You could facilitate this by placing an index on the `RecordDate` column, but you would still need to `ORDER BY` to see any effect.

Comment: The event in row3 occurred before row2 so I want to adjust the rows according to the date they occurred even if someone makes mistake to record row2 first. This looks like a bank statement, where withdrawals and payment are used to calculate balance and recorded the second they occurred. But my record is not done by computer but a human being who can make mistake anytime.